# How to convert a PFFile into a PFObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am using Parse. I have a PFFILE that I am retrieving using a Query. I need to save it, and i found that you normally use `saveEventualy`. But it doesn't support PFFile. So how can I turn the PFFile into a PFObject? Or else how save the image for offline? That's my code up to now:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];        
    [self GetImage];
}

- (void)enteredForeground:(NSNotification*) not
{
    [self GetImage];
}

-(void)GetImage
{    
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Image"];    
    [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"4tmub1uxVd" block:^(PFObject *imageObject, NSError >*error)        
    {        
        if (imageObject) {                
            PFFile *imageFile = imageObject[@"image"];               
            [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {               
                if (data) {                        
                    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];                       
                    if (image) {                        
                        self.imageview.image = image;                       
                    }                        
                } else {                        
                    NSLog(@"Error fetching image file: %@", error);                        
                }                    
            }];                
        } else {                
           NSLog(@"Error fetching object: %@", error);                
       }                                               
    }];

}
```

Comment: Why/when do you need to save it? You've just fetched it, and you haven't changed it...

Comment: @Handsomeguy The moment after fetching it, i have to save it

Comment: Save it where? On the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse has recently introduced a new method called local Data Store. It let's you store objects and files, update and retrieve them. Check out the documentation.

[Blog Post](http://blog.parse.com/2014/12/09/parse-local-datastore-for-ios/)

[Documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#localdatastore/iOS)
 That doesn't exactly answer your question, but it will achieve what you want it to!

Comment: Thanks. I haven't really looked into that app anymore... But thanks for the future reference!

Comment: this answer is wrong. you cannot save a PFFile to the local data store at this time (version 1.7.2)

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert a PFFile to a PFObject, but you don't need to. The `Image` PFObject class you're fetching in the code above has a property, with key `image`, that represents a PFFile. If you modify this, you'd save the parent object, which would save the updated file alongside it.

Comment: Do what? I'm not really sure what your question is or what you're trying to do.